# MessageEmbed is not defined (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this problem where it always says `MessageEmbed is not defined`! I don't know why it says that please help me! I have tried to solve this problem but nothing solved the problem!

```js
const wait = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);
const OWNER_ID = require("../../config.json").OWNER_ID;
const { MessageEmbed }= require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
var token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;

module.exports = {
     name: "restart",
    description: "restarts the bot",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const logMsg = `Command Used: \`RESTART\` \nUser: \`${interaction.user.id}\` \nChannel: \`${interaction.channel.id} (${interaction.channel.name})\``;
        client.channels.cache.get(client.config.errorLog).send(logMsg);
        try {
            if (interaction.user.id != OWNER_ID || ID) {
                await interaction.reply({content: "RESTARRR...",ephemeral: true});
                await wait(1000);
                await interaction.editReply({content:"Wait ... What?!",ephemeral: true});
                await wait(2000);
                return await interaction.editReply({content:"Bruh! You are not a developer, this command is not for you : )",ephemeral: true});
            }

            await interaction.reply("RESTARTING FAST AS F BOIIIIII ...").then((m) => {
                client.destroy(BOT_TOKEN);
                });
            await wait(2000).then((m) => {
                client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
            });
            await interaction.editReply("Damn! I'm Back ");
              
        } catch(err) {
            const errTag = client.config.errTag;
            client.channels.cache.get(client.config.ERROR_LOGS_CHANNEL).send(`**ERROR!** ${errTag} \n${err}\nCommand: \`RESTART\` \nChannel: \`${interaction.channel.id} (${interaction.channel.name})\` \n User: \`${interaction.user.id}\`\n`);
        }
        
    },
};
```

I have tried to solve this problem but nothing happened!

here the code in the command.js file

```js
timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
  setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

  try {
    command.run(client, message, args, p, cooldowns);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    let embed2000 = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription("There was an error executing that command.")
      .setColor("BLUE");
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2000] }).catch(console.error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please show your whole error. Include the error stack

Comment: [FATAL] Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
  <rejected> ReferenceError: MessageEmbed is not defined
      at module.exports (/home/runner/Bolt-Utilities/events/guild/command.js:134:21)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
}  reason:  MessageEmbed is not defined

Comment: that is the whole error

Comment: Can you show your `/Bolt-Utilities/events/guilds/command.js` around line 134?

Comment: sure let me get a ss

Comment: Please edit the code into the question instead of a screenshot

Comment: okay  gonna do that

Comment: added it into the message!

Comment: So the error is in command.js and MessageEmbed is not defined in that

Comment: how can i define it?

Comment: Define it with `const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")`

Comment: also in all of the other command the MessageEmbed works

Comment: now it says command.run is not a function

Comment: Because those are different files, but it's not defined in command.js

Comment: also in the command.js file

Comment: "*command.run is not a function*" - because the function is called execute

Comment: in line 132 is it

Comment: and now it says cannot read properties of reading id in the restart.js file